# Little help in translating C# code to Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, translation

I am using a custom listview control in my project which I found on code project. This control has a property of ImageGetter which used to set the images to column. Author provided the example to use it but it is written in C#. I tried to use online converters but all of them are unable to translate the code and also author of this code did not provided the answer to a question asked to provide VB.net code. So I need some one to translate the below code to VB.Net.

```
        this.olvColumn18.ImageGetter = delegate(object row) {
             if ("AEIOU".Contains(((Person)row).Name.Substring(0, 1)))
                return 0; 
            else if (((Person)row).Name.CompareTo("N") < 0)
                return 1; 
            else
                return 2; 
        };
```

In addition I want to ask what is delegate? is this a function or something else.
Here is the link of control

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

Comment: Basics of C# or VB or both. Sorry to say but just do it or leave it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use an anonymous delegate. You can simply create a function and use `AddressOf`, just as it is shown in the article.

```
Private Function PersonColumnImageGetter(object rowObject) As Object
    Dim p As Person = DirectCast(rowObject, Person)
    If "AEIOU".Contains(p.Name.Substring(0, 1)) Then
        Return 0
    Else If p.Name.CompareTo("N") < 0 Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return 2
    End If
End Function
```

And you can assign it using (the codeproject article uses `this`, but that's wrong for VB.NET, use `Me` instead):

```
Me.personColumn.ImageGetter = New ImageGetterDelegate(AddressOf PersonColumnImageGetter)
```

Or if you want to use an anonymous delegate:

```
Me.personColumn.ImageGetter =  Function (object rowObject) As Object
                                   Dim p As Person = DirectCast(rowObject, Person)
                                   If "AEIOU".Contains(p.Name.Substring(0, 1)) Then
                                       Return 0
                                   Else If p.Name.CompareTo("N") < 0 Then
                                       Return 1
                                   Else
                                       Return 2
                                   End If
                               End Function
```

I'd suggest you to read the VB.NET documentation (and if needed also the C# documentation) how to write things. Often, code examples on MSDN are available in both languages, so it is quite easy to learn both syntax's.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general solution: compile your code in debug mode, then decompile it to another language with a tool like Reflector. That's the charm of .NET.